# Finding the next/previous item from a list from a given substring

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to get set of tuples of previous and next string of a substring(second argument/input word) from a given a text (first argument) which has frequency less than 1. I a trying to loop over the text, find the input word, check if left/right word of the input word less frequent, then create a tuple and add it to it. trying to get all left and right item from input word but getting either
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`
or `String of character not the whole word.{('o', 'n'), ('t', 'l')}`\

```
for i in text:
        if i == second_arg:
          if i!=0:
              prev = str(text[i-1])
          elif i < len(text)-1:
              aft = str(text[i+1])
return set(prev, aft)
```

```
for indx, word in enumerate(text):
          if word == second_arg:
              if indx!=0:
                prev = (text[indx-1])
              if i!=(len(text)-1):  
                aft = (text[indx+1])
return prev, aft
print(function_name(text, "example"))
```

I cannot even get previous item in the list.
Thank you.
Note: text= text.split(),, it's a list. list of strings

Comment: You are looping over a string, so you each iteration you will pass a single character. You could do `text.split()` to transform your string in a list, containing separated words.

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers it's actually list. I have split it, removed all punctuations. did it all.

Comment: Could you provide all data to replicate your error? Also note that your indentation is off and you are calling `return` outside of a function, which is not possible.

Comment: As @MitchellOlislagers said, please provide the data you work with and correct your indentation so we can help you. Also providing an example of input and desired output could help us to help you.

Comment: I have sorted out, :) python 3 throws error for [ ] , it will be simply i-1, i+1, although it will give only integers. if I put string/text like text[aft], it gives the string in that position.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your variable *text* is a string variable. Doing the *for*-loop induces that the variable *i* is also a string. Python3 refuses to subtract a number to a string. Your problem could be solved by changing:

`for i in text:`

into

`for i in range(len(txt)):`

or

`for i,word in enumerate(text):`

Hope it helped a bit :)